# gson or jackson for google drive api

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Google Drive API comes with several versions of google-http-client-...

One is using gson, another is using jackson.

Currently, my app haven't decide to go for which JSON parser. May I know, is gson or jackson being recommended officially? Personally, I prefer gson due to its small size.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a huge fan of Jackson.

I've used Gson, Jackson, and the org.json parser.  They are all good, but I like the way Jackson's api works best.

Comment: cool. one thing i do not like on jackson api is that, they use checked exception.